# Error deserializing JSON file in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I am having a difficulty trying to extract data from the following JSON table:

```
    [
    {"type":"header","version":"4.8.3","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
    {"type":"database","name":"archaism_dictionary"},
    {"type":"table","name":"dictionary","database":"archaism_dictionary","data":
    [
    {"id":"0","word":"wordOne","synonym":null,"definition":"defOne"},
    {"id":"1","word":"wortTwo","synonym":null,"definition":"defTwo"}
    ]
    }
    ]
```

My goal is to get a string output for each "word" and each "definition". I have the following class which corresponds to the JSON file:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string database { get; set; }
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
    public object synonym { get; set; }
    public string definition { get; set; }
}
```

Finally this piece of code is supposed to retrieve the first word from the table in the string result:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary.Rootobject>>(rawJSON);
string result = list[0].Property1[0].data[0].word;
```

The .Property[0] returns null and the program gives me a null reference exception. Where is my code faulty and how should I accomplish this task? Thank you.

EDIT:
I am not sure whether this can mess up the rawJSON string but I get it like this:

```
rawJSON = File.ReadAllText(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory + fileName);
```

Comment: Could you please provide a complete valid json content? Otherwise, it would be difficult to find out the problem.

Comment: the first two elements in your data do not have a "data" property.  Have you actually examined the deserialized json?

Comment: you can copy your json and Paste Special in Visual Studio to create appropriate classes or use www.json2csharp.com site to see what classes you need to properly deserialize your json

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guide on posting code and [edit] post accordingly. In particular make sure to provide exact (but minimal) JSON that demonstrates the problem. Also since it is NRE make sure to review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it.

Comment: I'd love to help, but without a valid json example, I can't.

Comment: Hello all, thank you for replying. I am now using the first JSON, which Claudio provided.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to null handle(json NullValueHandling) below is my code please take a look :

```
string stringJson = @"{
                              'Property1':[
                                {'type':'header','version':'4.8.3','comment':'Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin'},
                               {'type':'database','name':'archaism_dictionary'},
                               {'type':'table','name':'dictionary','database':'archaism_dictionary','data':
                               [
                                {'id':'0','word':'wordOne','synonym':null,'definition':'defOne'},
                                 {'id':'1','word':'wortTwo','synonym':null,'definition':'defTwo'}
                              ]
                              }
                             ]
                            }";

        try
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
            };
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseResponse>(stringJson,settings);
            string result = list.Property1[2].data[0].word;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
```

Models :

```
public class WordData
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
    public object synonym { get; set; }
    public string definition { get; set; }
}

public class PropertyData
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string database { get; set; }
    public List<WordData> data { get; set; }
}

public class BaseResponse
{
    public List<PropertyData> Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it will help you

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is more likely that your input json is something like this:

```
[
{"type":"header","version":"4.8.3","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
{"type":"database","name":"archaism_dictionary"},
{"type":"table","name":"dictionary","database":"archaism_dictionary","data":
[
{"id":"0","word":"wordOne","synonym":null,"definition":"defOne"},
{"id":"1","word":"wortTwo","synonym":null,"definition":"defTwo"}
]
```

Note square brakets, they're important.

If I guessed it right, you'll want to deserialize like this:

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Class1>>(rawJSON);
string result = list[2].data[0].word;
```

Note: your original code would work only if your input json were:

```
{
  "Property1":[
    {"type":"header","version":"4.8.3","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
    {"type":"database","name":"archaism_dictionary"},
    {"type":"table","name":"dictionary","database":"archaism_dictionary","data":
      [
        {"id":"0","word":"wordOne","synonym":null,"definition":"defOne"},
        {"id":"1","word":"wortTwo","synonym":null,"definition":"defTwo"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and use

```
var myRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(rawJSON);
string result = myRoot.Property1[2].data[0].word;
```

Comment: Thank you, I replaced the JSON with yours (the first one) and the command to yours but I still get the null as a returning value.

Comment: Had a typo in the indexer, it is list[2] instead of list[0]. I edited the answer and added code for secpnd json. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

@ Claudio Valerio provide the right json data.

Based on my test, you could try the code below to get the `word` in the list.

Json daya:

```
{
"Property1":[
{"type":"header","version":"4.8.3","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
{"type":"database","name":"archaism_dictionary"},
{"type":"table","name":"dictionary","database":"archaism_dictionary","data":
  [
    {"id":"0","word":"wordOne","synonym":null,"definition":"defOne"},
    {"id":"1","word":"wortTwo","synonym":null,"definition":"defTwo"}
  ]
  }
 ]
}
```

Class from JSON data:

```
 public class Rootobject
{
    public Property1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Property1
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string version { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string database { get; set; }
    public Datum[] data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
    public object synonym { get; set; }
    public string definition { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
  string rawJSON = @"{
  'Property1':[
    {'type':'header','version':'4.8.3','comment':'Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin'},
   {'type':'database','name':'archaism_dictionary'},
   {'type':'table','name':'dictionary','database':'archaism_dictionary','data':
   [
    {'id':'0','word':'wordOne','synonym':null,'definition':'defOne'},
     {'id':'1','word':'wortTwo','synonym':null,'definition':'defTwo'}
  ]
  }
 ]
}";
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(rawJSON);
        string result = list.Property1[2].data[0].word;
```

[image]